# Rails wicked_pdf & chartkick not working - showing loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, chartkick, wkhtmltopdf-binary

I'm trying to make chartkick work with wicked_pdf but all it does is show a loading sign:
[image: loading image]

I'm using wicked_pdf version: 2.1.0,
wkhtmltopdf-binary version:0.12.6.5

I've tried replacing it with wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge (0.12.6.0) with no luck.

Controller code:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do 
      render pdf:"report_page",
             javascript_delay: 1000
    end
  end
```

.pdf.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'dashboard', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag('bootstrap') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.google.com/jsapi" %>
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "chartkick" %>
<div class="container">
      <%= line_chart data_for_pdf_student_graphs(data_here), id: "1-graph", width: "900px", height: "500px"%>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out what to try next, I've tried using a high javascript_delay with no luck.

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix it? I recently had this stopped working too.